# Why a job of dbms_job is BROKEN

Tags: oracle, jobs, log

I have Oracle job that uses dbms_job package. I see that it becomes BROKEN:

```
Select job,what,BROKEN from dba_jobs; 
-------- ------------ -----------
1   statspack.snap; Y
```

I would like to know the reason it's BROKEN

ASAIK for scheduled job we have dba_scheduler_job_log view where we can see the fail reason, but what about dbms_job jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And that is one of the reasons why everyone should forget `DBMS_JOB` and use `DBMS_SCHEDULER`.

`DBMS_JOB` jobs do not have history or any logging enabled. If a `DBMS_JOB` job fails, that should be reported in the database alert log. If a `DBMS_JOB` fails 16 times in a row, it will be automatically marked as broken.

Your job either failed 16 times in a row and was marked broken, or someone manually set it as broken.

Comment: Thank you Balazs! you are like Oracle Jesus here, come to save us! Thank you so much again :)